# How to use Pan Gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer, pan

Im a beginner programmer with Xcode 5 and was attempting to write code to allow a user to move a image with input from the users touch.

So far, I believe that my code is correct but i believe I'm missing something as the UIImage refuses move. Although when attempt to test it with NSLog I don't get a response which shows it working. My guess it that I have to make a custom class for the image and if so would I do this and how would I link it.

For example

```
  @implementation StartPage
  - (IBAction)HandlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender; {
  NSLog(@"panning"); //Testing to check if the image moves when touched by user.

  CGPoint NetTranslation ;
  CGPoint Translation =
 [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender translationInView: _Imageview ];

  sender.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (

  NetTranslation.x += Translation.x,
  NetTranslation.y += Translation.y);
  enter code here
  if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
   NetTranslation.x += Translation.x;
   NetTranslation.y += Translation.y;
  }
```

}

Comment: "Although when attempt to test it with NSLog I don't get a response which shows it working." so your problem is that gesture recogniser not works for your view. Please add code where you initialize gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `HandlePan` method is not called check that your _Imageview has user interactions enabled:

```
_Imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was a little special and didn't check my links between pages. Its all working fine now.

Answer (score 4):

While using any Gesture you should use following steps,

Now you are using pan gesture so i am giving following steps to add pan gesture,

1. Add delegate like to your header file [ .h file ]

   ```
   @interface ViewName : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
   ```
2. Declare that gesture

   ```
   @property (nonatomic,strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
   ```
3. Allocate that gesture

   ```
   pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
   ```
4. Mention where these delegate methods are present

   ```
   pan.delegate = self;
   ```
5. Adding that gesture to the view like

   ```
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
   ```
6. Defining the handlePan method like as

   ```
   - (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
   { 
      // code for pan gesture here
   }
   ```

I think you missed to do something... Hope this will solve your problem, check whether you added UIGestureRecognizer in header file or not...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was a little special and didn't check my links between pages. Its all working fine now.

Comment: Gr8, hey dude if u find this answer is useful then you may upvote it...Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

**For swift language we can do like this:**

Take a view and set IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewDrag: UIView!

var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
```

Write this pretty code on viewDidLoad()

```
 panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.draggedView(_:)))
    viewDrag.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    viewDrag.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

This is method which is calling while gesture recognized

```
 @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(viewDrag)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    viewDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewDrag.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

**100% working and tested**